# how to get consumer key and secret with application token using oAuth?

Tags: oauth, quickbooks

I am using oAuth to call Intuit Quickbook Onlinde data API.

Is there any method to get comsumerKey and Secret ussing App Token value in oAuth ?

thank,
manish

Answer (score 2):

You can use this - https://appcenter.intuit.com/Playground/OAuth

Connect to QB Ref (3 legged Oauth) Ref - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0010_getting_started/0020_connect/0010_from_within_your_app

You can refer the sample JAVA/.Net app as well to generated accessKey, accessSecret against your QBO account(relam).

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the answer but based on only app token is there anyway to get consumerkey and token using oauth classes ?

Comment: When you create a QB IA app in appcenter, then you get the following 3 tokens - Apptoken, consumerKey and consumerSecert. You need to use these three tokens to get accessToken and accessSecret corresponding to your QBO account. This is the only way of getting OAuth tokens. From the link below, you'll get all apps created by you in appcenter. https://developer.intuit.com/Application/List

Answer (score 1):

As the [official document](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0070_glossary) says:

Both Consumer Key and Secret are assigned to your app by Intuit and displayed in the app profile on the IPP developer site.

> consumer key
>   An OAuth value, used by the app to identify itself to the Intuit OAuth provider service.   **The consumer key is generated when you create the app on the IPP developer site and is displayed on the Manage App tab.**  The Development and Production instances of an app have different consumer key values.  A consumer key is required in the header of an HTTP request to  Data Services for QuickBooks or the QuickBooks API.
>
> consumer secret
>   An OAuth consumer secret.  A secret used by the app to establish ownership of the consumer key.  **The consumer secret is generated when you create the app on the IPP developer site and is displayed on the Manage App tab.**  The Development and Production instances of an app have different consumer secret values.  A consumer secret is required in the header of an HTTP request to  Data Services for QuickBooks or the QuickBooks API.

And here is a [tutorial of Implement OAuth in Your App](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0010_getting_started/0020_connect/0010_from_within_your_app/implement_oauth_in_your_app).

Comment: thanks for the answer but based on only app token is there anyway to get consumerkey and token using oauth classes or is it possible or not ?